# Link with a parameter is not recognized

Tags: support, hyperlinks

A link with parameters:

`:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35382295/how-can-i-group-by-date-from-star-time-to-end-time-range-in-ruby-on-rails?noredirect=1#comment58470095_35382295`

Is recognized when written as part of the text:
:[How can I group by date from star time to end time range in Ruby On Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35382295/how-can-i-group-by-date-from-star-time-to-end-time-range-in-ruby-on-rails?noredirect=1#comment58470095_35382295), but is not recognized when used in the `[label](url)` form: like this.

Comment: By the way, this was from a different person's post, not mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the initial colon in round brackets [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35382295/how-can-i-group-by-date-from-star-time-to-end-time-range-in-ruby-on-rails?noredirect=1#comment58470095_35382295) and the link displays and works correctly.

A URL starts with a scheme, not a colon. If you look carefully at the inline link the colon is not underlined, the inline link parser just skips it and starts linkifying after that.

Comment: You are right. ...